# Explain statement in Collections doc.oracle

Tags: java, collections

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add(E)

In the above link, it states:

> If a collection refuses to add a particular element for any reason other than that it already contains the element, it must throw an exception (rather than returning false).
>   This preserves the invariant that a collection always contains the specified element after this call returns.

It would be of much help if someone could explain what the last sentence means. Does it mean the value of .add() would be added to the collection even if it throws an exception?

Also, is it possible for the collection to prohibit duplicates and throw an exception?

Comment: The quote above doesn't make sense without the first sentence in the [method's Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add(E)): "Ensures that this collection contains the specified element". That is the invariant that OP's quote refers to.

Comment: It means that after `coll.add(x)` completes normally (without exceptions), `coll.contains(x)` must return `true`. It doesn't specify anything about what happens when it _does_ throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

The point is: when the method throws an exception, it doesn't **return** any more.

It is either **returning** or **throwing an exception**. So, when you write code that uses *add()* ... and that call doesn't throw on you, you know that the object you added **must** be in the collection. Without the need to further check that boolean result value that *add()* returned to you.

You see, *add()* could very much return false (when the collection happens to be a set, and "new" object was already present). That depends on the type of collection you are actually dealing with. The point here is: as the javadoc says, that boolean result only tells you about the state of the collection itself (did that change, yes or no).

Comment: `...add() could very much return false (because the new object was already present,` ***`and the collection is a set, which doesn't allow for duplicates)`*** ---> There are collections which permit duplicates too!

Comment: I have to admit, I dont get your exact point. add() can return false (for a set); and yes, other collection types will always return true upon calls to that method.

Comment: Though I'm myself a non-native English speaker, but, I feel, as written currently, the line means that all collections are sets, which don't allow for duplicates

Comment: I see. Hope it is more clear now (although I think it was correct before, too, but maybe slightly misleading).

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful A native speaker would indeed notice that because GhostCat wrote "and _the_ collection is a set", the implication is that there are other collections which are not sets. Had he written "and _a_ collection is a set", then you'd be right. It's certainly more clear now, but wasn't outright wrong originally.

Comment: One of those days ... during this week I saw to other folks giving short answers, kinda "ok level" quality ... but because that SO question was showing up as "hot" ... they got 15, 20 upvotes in a few minutes. For really "almost below average" content. And here I am ... almost nothing happens, but people discussing the quality of my usage of the English language. No, not complaining, just ranting ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat - SORRY, but, It seems the fault is in myself. Anyways, +1.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - Noted, Thanks. Need to work hard upon my grammar.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Dont be too hard with yourself. It is still true that many many people here are not native English speakers. So short, precise sentences are still something to go for. It doesn't help when some sentence says "A", but some people understand "AB"; just because of too subtle wording/usage of grammar when expressing "A".

Answer (score 1):

Read the statement clearly:

> boolean add(E e)
>
> Ensures that this collection contains the specified element (optional
> operation).
>
> **Returns true if this collection changed as a result of the
> call. (Returns false if this collection does not permit duplicates and
> already contains the specified element.)**

---

Your question:

> Also, is it possible for the collection to prohibit duplicates and
> throw an exception?

As highlighted above, it depends on the collection which is being operated.

> If a collection refuses to add a particular element for any reason other than that it already contains the element, it must throw an exception (rather than returning false). This preserves the invariant that a collection always contains the specified element after this call returns.

This simply means that the collection should remain invariant in reflecting its state.

If an element is added successfully, it must be available. You don't need to get the return boolean variable to know whether this value was added OR not.

But, if not, then it should throw exception, thereby, no longer the usual (successful) return.